# What syntax would I use to echo a value to an existing input box. Populate the box with the value

Tags: jquery

I have json array with a value that needs to be populated into an already existing input box. What syntax do I use inside my document.ready success function?

Here is my array:

```
{"rpt":"132","success":1,"message":"ok"}
```

The html in my form is:

```
<input type="hidden" id="rpt" value="">
```

My success function in the JQ script:

```
success: function(data)
```

I guess what I need is within the success function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing something like:

```
$('#rpt').val(data['rpt']);
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val